# Alternative to column named "DATE" on Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm migrating a database to Oracle, where the word "DATE" is reserved.
What alternative can i use? Which one do you guys use?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can associate the date column name with the item it's connected. Let's say you have a table with invoices, your date column could be named `invoice_date` or `invoice_dat`.

For me, this looks very good to read and it makes statements with join operations a bit more readable.

Comment: Wanted to point out that this is a bit like smurf naming, which I personally find good to avoid.  In this case, though, we're stuck working around the issue, and prefixing it with what might be the table name may be unavoidable.

Answer (score 4):

Good chance to give the column name a little more context: `REG_DATE`, `UPD_DATE`, `EXPIRATION_DATE`, `BIRTHDATE` etc

Answer (score 2):

Although not recommended practice, it is possible to use `DATE` as a column name by enclosing it in double-quotes, as in

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TAB
  (NUM_COL   NUMBER,
   "DATE"    DATE);
```

This is an option if, for example, you have queries which uses this column name frequently and are unwilling to change it.  One drawback to doing this is that you'd have to put the column name in double-quotes everywhere it is used, as in

```
SELECT *
  FROM TEST_TAB
  WHERE "DATE" BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                   AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
```

On the whole it would be better to follow the recommendations of @stb or @Thilo to change the name to something more meaningful.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `DT` or `TS` (TimeStamp) or `DATEX` or `DATE_` name.

If you have several date columns in single table use `_DATE` as suffix or `DATE_` as prefix.

Alternatively enclose `"DATE"` in double quotes, but `DT` is shorter.